# Negative unit testing for Enum setter

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

Here is an example for a positive test

```
@ParameterizedTest
@EnumSource(ProblemUrgencyEnum.class)
@DisplayName("Given a valid Urgency, set Urgency, validate given and set are equal")
void setUrgency(ProblemUrgencyEnum aEnum){
    problemInboundBean.setUrgency(aEnum);
    assertEquals(aEnum, problemInboundBean.getUrgency());
}
```

Now, is there a way to write a negative unit test for the above setter function?
I can't seem to find an example of a negative test involving enum setters and I'm starting to think it's not something that should be done. Is this the case?

Comment: As you say, it's not possible. All values are tested and no other value (that is not in the enum) can be passed.

Comment: What would you like the "negative" test case to test for?